# Adding a dimension to an array

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, reshape, nifti

If I have an array that I loaded from a nifti file with shape `(112, 176, 112)` and I want to add a fourth dimension but not be limited to shape `(112, 176, 112, 3)`

Why does this code allow me to add however many layers in the 4th dimension I want:

```
data = np.ones((112, 176, 112, 20), dtype=np.int16)
print(data.shape)
    >>>(112, 176, 112, 20)
```

But when I try to add a higher layer number to the fourth dimension of my file I get an error. The code only works correctly if `axis = 3`. If `axis = 2` the shape is `(112, 176, 336, 1)`

```
filepath = '3channel.nii'  
img = nib.load(filepath)
img = img.get_fdata()
print(img.shape)
    >>>(112, 176, 112)
img2 = img.reshape((112, 176, 112, -1))
img2 = np.concatenate([img2, img2, img2], axis = 20)
```

Error:

```
AxisError: axis 20 is out of bounds for array of dimension 4
```

Comment: what do you get when you `print(img.shape)`?

Comment: Why are you using `axis=20`?   Do you understand what the `axis` parameter means?   20 doesn't make sense when you are working with 4d arrays.  You aren't defining 20d array - that would be an exceptional case.  Are confused about dimensions?

Comment: print(img.shape)>>>`(112, 176, 112)`

Comment: @hpaulj I am learning how to do auto segmentation with tensorflow. I successfully segmented a bone with just the background and bone label. So now I am trying to segment multiple materials. One thing I read was that I have to set the number of labels in my shape. Example, `(images,x,y,z,label)`  should be how my training data shape should look, meaning I need to get `(x,y,z,label)` in order first. `images` will be how many files i am using to train. `20` for the label was an extreme example, it would probably be closer to `5-8`  labels.

Comment: Yes, but that is just another layer in the 4th dimension.  Image0 is (x,y,z,0), Image1 is (x,y,z,1)...; you still only have 4 dimensions.   If there is a single label, that can be kept track of differently (1D only required, one element per image, correct?)

Comment: No, since I am doing a 3D volume it expects a it to have 5 dimensions. This is the error that generates if I try to an input with 4 dimensions: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (104, 112, 176, 112)`. I am using 104 volumes, with shape 112,176,112. Since I am using the `data_format = 'channels_last'` my shape needs to be  `(images,x,y,z,label)`.

Answer (score 0):

@hpaulj got it, I was looking this up, and this shows the issue; note the shape of the arrays. I modified the original array so you can see what is being added...

```
import numpy as np

data = np.ones((112, 176, 115, 20), dtype=np.int16)

data2=np.ones((112, 176, 115), dtype=np.int16)

data2a = data2.reshape((112, 176, 115, -1))
print(data2a.shape)

print("concatenate...")
img2 = np.concatenate([data2a, data2a, data2a],axis=0)
print(img2.shape)

img2 = np.concatenate([data2a, data2a, data2a],axis=1)
print(img2.shape)

img2 = np.concatenate([data2a, data2a, data2a],axis=2)
print(img2.shape)

img2 = np.concatenate([data2a, data2a, data2a],axis=3)
print(img2.shape)

# This throws the error
img2 = np.concatenate([data2a, data2a, data2a],axis=4)
print(img2.shape)
```

Comment: Axes like all of numpy indexing starts with 0.  With a 4d array like `data2d`, using `axis` in the [0,1,2,3] range makes sense; 4 and large does not.  Axis in effect indexes the shape tuple, `(112, 176, 115, -1)`.

Comment: Yep!  I was curious, so I figured I'd post it to make it clearer to @rzaratx...